# Updating an installed VB.Net program

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net program.  I recently just compiled a new version of the program, but the old version is already installed on the computer.  Is there a way to update the program without:

```
1) Uninstalling and re-installing the program
2) Running the program (On load it runs queries, and emails results).  I don't want it to run until it's Windows Scheduled time.
```

Comment: How did you install it previously?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem. From what I read out of your question I would give the answer: Just copy the new .EXE over the old one. Since I would guess that this is not feasible in your case, you need to clarify what your want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard `Setup` or `MSI builder` for your app, as you update the program and increment the version the installer will know this and update your app without uninstalling being done manually.

Examples:

1. [InnoSetup](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=inno%20setup&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jrsoftware.org%2F&ei=eagTU6-LDIaCyAHel4DwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEvW0VoRn9J_ZgYsLhtm64AGqq1FA&sig2=FA_XMbmkzoKel99zVACmzw&bvm=bv.61965928,d.aWc) - free
2. VS Setup project - pro or higher version no express versions
3. [InstallAware](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=msi%20builder&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CHcQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.installaware.com%2Flanding%2Fmsi-builder.htm&ei=VqgTU_j-LseSyAHz4YCADw&usg=AFQjCNGoV8rYDp7QyrtVzdA4uYjNtBeqlA&sig2=xNjsYjtg5jjp8zhP3Zxu1Q&bvm=bv.61965928,d.aWc) - not free